# Cannot access phpmyadmin locally

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am aware that this has been answered multiple times, I get the 1045 error, I am trying to follow https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/, but get this when trying to follow the steps:

Michaels-Air:~ michaelnares$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Michaels-Air:~ michaelnares$ cd /tmp
Michaels-Air:tmp michaelnares$ ls
com.apple.launchd.Uoy1kKt9Ag    com.apple.launchd.bRUV1JxWGF    mysql.sock.lock
Michaels-Air:tmp michaelnares$

Doing sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock doesn't create the necessary file, what else can I do please?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your mySQL instance is not running?

To check use:

```
 ps aux |grep mysqld
```

Comment: Michaels-Air:tmp michaelnares$ ps aux | grep mysqld
_mysql             506   0.0  2.0  2829668 171396   ??  Ss    2:15pm   0:01.17 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
michaelnares      1320   0.0  0.0  2432804    780 s000  S+    2:52pm   0:00.00 grep mysqld
Michaels-Air:tmp michaelnares$

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

brew reinstall mysql worked, not quite sure why.